# Android/Java - JSONException, java.util.HashMap cannot be converted to JSONObject API < 21

Tags: android, json, hashmap

I am running into a very strange problem on devices running API < 21.

I have the following JSONObject

```
{  
   "saturday":"{notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-16T08:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-16T15:00:00-05:00}",
   "wednesday":"{notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-20T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-20T18:45:00-05:00}",
   "tuesday":"{notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-19T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-19T18:45:00-05:00}",
   "friday":"{notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-22T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-22T18:45:00-05:00}",
   "thursday":"{notes=Appointments & Walk-Ins, open=2016-01-21T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-21T18:45:00-05:00}",
   "monday":"{notes=null, open=null, close=null}",
   "sunday":"{notes=null, open=null, close=null}"
}
```

When attempting to get the JSONObject for a given day, on devices running API >= 21 I am about to use the following example code

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("tuesday")
```

which successfully returns a JSONObject, however, on devices running API < 21 the same exact code is throwing

```
Value {notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-19T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-19T18:45:00-05:00} at tuesday of type java.util.HashMap cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Why is this happening?

Edit: My mapping code isn't anything special -

```
JSONObject loungeHours = new JSONObject(ParseCloud.<Map>callFunction(STORE_HOURS_ENDPOINT, new HashMap<String, Object>()));
```

When analyzed with the debugger, loungeHours is successfully populated with the following

```
{  
   "saturday":"{notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-16T08:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-16T15:00:00-05:00}",
   "wednesday":"{notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-20T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-20T18:45:00-05:00}",
   "tuesday":"{notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-19T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-19T18:45:00-05:00}",
   "friday":"{notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-22T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-22T18:45:00-05:00}",
   "thursday":"{notes=Appointments & Walk-Ins, open=2016-01-21T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-21T18:45:00-05:00}",
   "monday":"{notes=null, open=null, close=null}",
   "sunday":"{notes=null, open=null, close=null}"
}
```

Full stacktrace

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-19T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-19T18:45:00-05:00} at tuesday of type java.util.HashMap cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:573)
W/System.err:     at com.hitchtech.adamsbarberlounge.parse.ParseDelegate.getOpenHours(ParseDelegate.java:127)
W/System.err:     at com.hitchtech.adamsbarberlounge.application.main.LoungeDetailFragment$LoungeInfoCardController.populateHours(LoungeDetailFragment.java:247)
W/System.err:     at com.hitchtech.adamsbarberlounge.application.main.LoungeDetailFragment$LoungeInfoCardController.<init>(LoungeDetailFragment.java:105)
W/System.err:     at com.hitchtech.adamsbarberlounge.application.main.LoungeDetailFragment.setupLoungeInfoCardController(LoungeDetailFragment.java:73)
W/System.err:     at com.hitchtech.adamsbarberlounge.application.main.LoungeDetailFragment.onViewCreated(LoungeDetailFragment.java:64)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:441)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your mapping code

Comment: Json object like. {Key:"value",key:"value2"}

Comment: What is the error full trace

Comment: @sector11 stacktrace posted

Comment: @QuangDoan You're right, looking at it more closely, it does appear to be invalid.. it is missing quotes. Why would API < 21 not quote it while API >= 21 does?

Comment: I try your JSON in AVD with API 22, got exception `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {notes=Walk-Ins Only, open=2016-01-19T09:00:00-05:00, close=2016-01-19T18:45:00-05:00} at tuesday of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: @BNK Yes, for some reason lower API's get invalid JSON back from my service call... I have no idea why this is happening.